# Docker build command can't find package.json

Tags: docker, npm-install, package.json, docker-build

In my Dockerfile in `docker/my-project-node/` folder I have `RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps --only=production --no-optional`.

I want to run docker build locally and see if everything works fine.

When I run `docker build -t my-project-image .` I get this npm error:

```
#9 0.913 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#9 0.913 npm ERR! syscall open
#9 0.914 npm ERR! path /app/package.json
#9 0.914 npm ERR! errno -2
#9 0.916 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
#9 0.917 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#9 0.917 npm ERR! enoent
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates bash

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY . .

RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps --only=production --no-optional

CMD ["npm","run", "start:prod"]
```

What's wrong in my docker file?

Comment: Do you have the packages.json file in the host folder from where you are running your docker build command?

Comment: @ManishDash no. The docker build command I run from where the Dockerfile is `docker/my-project-node/Dockerfile`. The package.json is in the root of the project

Comment: yeah so thats the issue. In your command - the `.` that you have at the end - is the path to the "docker build context"

Comment: try `docker build -t image-name <path of the root where package.json is>`

Comment: @ManishDash ah got it. From the root I have to do `docker build . -t my-web-app -f docker/my-project-node//Dockerfile`

Comment: @ManishDash now I get a new error `Error: Cannot find module '/app/scripts/generate-gql-types.js'`. I have to `COPY` that file in my `Dockerfile` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245684/discussion-between-manish-dash-and-meez).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong `build context` to docker.

The `build context` is the directory Docker starts working from and all the `COPY` commands find the files from this path.

There are 2 ways to properly specify this:

- Run the command from the root of your project and specify the Dockerfile path explicitly if its not on the root. `docker build -t my-web-app -f docker/my-project-node/Dockerfile`
- In the docker command, specify the root you want. `docker build -t my-web-app ../..` (as your root is 2 folders up)

Finally, please look at `docker-compose`. All these pesky docker commands can be beautifully represented in a docker-compose file like this:

```
# docker-compose.yaml placed at root of the project
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: "example1"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/my-project-node/Dockerfile

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Once the file is created, simply run `docker-compose up -d` to create and run the containers, and `docker-compose down` to shutdown and remove the containers :)